# Classifying cohomology

Tags: cohomology, model-theory, topos-theory

In his 1973 topos seminar in Buffalo (the tapes are now [freely available online](https://agrothendieck.github.io/)!), Grothendieck said:

> The cohomology of a topos associated to an algebraic structure should be called the "classifying cohomology" of this algebraic structure, which I think has significance.

In modern terminology: each geometric theory $\mathbb T$ induces a classifying topos $\mathcal E_\mathbb T$, whose cohomology groups
$$H^n(\mathcal E_\mathbb T, A)$$
for abelian groups $A$ in $\mathcal E_\mathbb T$ might be interesting and tell us something about $\mathbb T$. [Similarly for first-order theories.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/414568/do-pretopoi-have-cohomology-and-homotopy-groups/414654#414654)

In fact, in *[Pursuing stacks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2111.01000)* Grothendieck says the same (see page 7):

> There is a general theorem for the existence of universal structures, covering all these cases - for instance there is a "classifying topos" for most algebro-geometric structures, whose cohomology say should be viewed as the "classifying cohomology" of the structure species considered.

**Question:** Has someone thought or written about this? Could that have applications in model theory?